# Combine two dataframes without using for loop

Tags: pandas

First Dataframe

| Primary_id | Age | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 45 | Male |
| 2 | 32 | Female |
| 3 | 35 | Male |

Second Dataframe

| id | Disease | duration | primary_id_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Diabetes | 10 | 1 |
| 2 | Hypertension | 20 | 1 |
| 3 | Cataract | 20 | 3 |

Combined Dataframe

| id | Age | Gender | Disease1 | duration1 | Disease2 | Duration2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 45 | Male | Diabetes | 10 | Hypertension | 20 |
| 2 | 32 | Female |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | 35 | Male | Cataract | 20 |  |  |

Without using for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [DataFrame.stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [DataFrame.unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) to transform the dataframe, to get the result.

```py
# for every primary_id create a Disease tag num
# e.g. as for primary_id 1:  Diabetes-1, Hypertension-2
df2['tag'] = 1
df2['tag'] = df2.groupby('primary_id_id')['tag'].cumsum()

# use stack and unstack to transform the dataframe
df2n = df2.set_index(['primary_id_id','tag'])[['Disease','duration']].stack()  
  
# swap the index level and unstack   
df3 = df2n.swaplevel(1).unstack().unstack()

# join to df1 to get result
df_result = df1.join(df3, on='Primary_id', how='left')
# rename columns
df_result.columns = [col if isinstance(col, str) else f'{col[1]}_{col[0]}' for col in df_result.columns]
```

result:

```
print(df2n)
    primary_id_id  tag          
    1              1    Disease         Diabetes
                        duration              10
                   2    Disease     Hypertension
                        duration              20
    3              1    Disease         Cataract
                        duration              20
    dtype: object


print(df3)
    tag                   1                      2         
                    Disease duration       Disease duration
    primary_id_id                                          
    1              Diabetes       10  Hypertension       20
    3              Cataract       20           NaN      NaN
    
print(df_result)

       Primary_id  Age  Gender Disease_1 duration_1     Disease_2 duration_2
    0           1   45    Male  Diabetes         10  Hypertension         20
    1           2   32  Female       NaN        NaN           NaN        NaN
    2           3   35    Male  Cataract         20           NaN        NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `groupby` and `agg` to convert the `dataframe2` into `x`
then convert this `x` into `val_df` i.e convert each list element into the separate column.

final step would be merging the `df1` with modified `df2(val_df)`

```
x = df2.drop('id',axis=1).groupby('primary_id_id').agg({'Disease': list, 'duration': list}).reset_index()

val_df = pd.DataFrame([])
for col in ['Disease', 'duration']:
    val_df = pd.concat([val_df, pd.DataFrame(x[col].values.tolist()).add_prefix(col)], axis=1)
val_df = val_df.join(x['primary_id_id'])


df_final = pd.merge(df1,val_df, left_on='Primary_id', right_on='primary_id_id', how='outer').drop('primary_id_id', axis=1)
```

---

**x:**

```
    primary_id_id   Disease                     duration
0   1               [Diabetes, Hypertension]    [10, 20]
1   3               [Cataract]                  [20]
```

---

**val_df:**

```
    Disease0    Disease1      duration0 duration1   primary_id_id
0   Diabetes    Hypertension  10        20.0        1
1   Cataract    None          20        NaN         3
```

---

**df_final:**

```
    Primary_id  Age Gender  Disease0    Disease1    duration0  duration1 
0   1           45  Male    Diabetes    Hypertension 10.0      20.0      
1   2           32  Female  NaN         NaN          NaN       NaN       
2   3           35  Male    Cataract    None         20.0      NaN
```